# How can I start a websocket connection with a docker API in Go with TLS enabled?

Tags: docker, go, ssl, websocket, containers

### Docker API configuration

According to [Docker APIs documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerAttachWebsocket) we can attach a container via a websocket. I set up TLS to my Docker daemon’s host machine according to these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket). I used the following options:

```
// $HOST=hostname of my pc
// 192.168.1.X DHCP address of my computer
$ echo subjectAltName = DNS:$HOST,IP:192.168.1.X,IP:127.0.0.1 >> extfile.cnf
$ dockerd \
    --tlsverify \
    --tlscacert=ca.pem \
    --tlscert=server-cert.pem \
    --tlskey=server-key.pem \
    -H=0.0.0.0:2376
$ docker --tlsverify \
    --tlscacert=ca.pem \
    --tlscert=cert.pem \
    --tlskey=key.pem \
    -H=0.0.0.0:2376 version
```

Docker tells us to make sure that “Common Name” matches the hostname we use to connect to Docker when asked to incorporate information in our certificate request. Pinging my hostname I get 127.0.1.1.

### Container networking architecture

I try to connect to the API on the address of my DHCP address from a docker container that is on a bridge network with other docker containers different to that of the host.

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                DRIVER    SCOPE
XXXXXXXXXX     host                host      local
XXXXXXXXXX     containers_network  bridge    local
```

There is a main api let's call it container 'api' that proxies calls to a server running Go code using http, container 'shell'. The 'shell' receives information about the Docker daemon ip (I use my DHCP address), port, container id, attachment options, etc.. to use from the 'api'. It receives the certificates that it will use to connect to the daemon from another container.

## Issue

If I run a curl command from my local terminal (not from a container) such as I get a response corresponding to what I requested:

```
curl https://DHCP_ADDRESS:2376/images/json \                                                          name@name-pc
  --cert ~/.docker/cert.pem \
  --key ~/.docker/key.pem \
  --cacert ~/.docker/ca.pem
```

If I ping my DHCP_ADDRESS from a container I receive packets normally. However, when I try to initiate a websocket connection from the 'shell' container the logs of the docker daemon give me:

```
http: TLS handshake error from container_ip_address:container_port: EOF
```

## Go code of the 'shell' container

The server in 'shell' has to handle two websockets. One sends keystrokes from the ui to 'shell' which in turn sends received keystrokes to the container through the second websocket (the one that connects securely with the docker API).

```
func docker_ExecRequest(opts *DockerExecOptions) (*http.Request, error) {
    //create empty url to be populated
    u := &url.URL{}
    u.Scheme = "https"
    u.Host = "DHCP_ADDRESS:2376"

    switch u.Scheme {
    case "https":
        u.Scheme = "wss"
    case "http":
        u.Scheme = "ws"
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unrecognised URL scheme in %v", u)
    }

    u.Path = fmt.Sprintf("/containers/%s/attach/ws", opts.Container_id)
    u.RawQuery = "stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&logs=1&stream=1&tty=1"
    log.Print(u.String())
    return &http.Request{
        Method: http.MethodGet,
        URL:    u,
    }, nil
}

func handleDocker(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    /..../
    DockerConfigCredentials, err := GetDockerConfigCredentials(/.../)
    opts := &DockerExecOptions{
        Host:       DockerConfigCredentials.Host,
        Port:       DockerConfigCredentials.Port,
        Container_id: vars["container_id"],
        Name:       vars["name"],
        Cluster:    vars["cluster"],
    }
    /...../
    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(DockerConfigCredentials.Cert_file), []byte(DockerConfigCredentials.Key_file))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(DockerConfigCredentials.Ca_cert_file))
    cfg := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        RootCAs:      caCertPool,
    }

    dialer := &websocket.Dialer{
        TLSClientConfig:  cfg,
        HandshakeTimeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    req, err := docker_ExecRequest(opts)
    podConn, d, err := dialer.Dial(req.URL.String(), req.Header)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Print(d.Body) // websocket: bad handshake
    defer podConn.Close()
    /..../
}
```

## Questions

- From what I understand the docker API is reachable from the container. If the configurations of the certificates/dockerd/docker don't make sense give me feedback. I remind you that I want the daemon to be my local computer with tcp bindings and TLS enabled so I can test connecting to it from a docker container.
- The certificates are in the form of ---begin...----/nXXXX/n...endcertificate--- . Is the above code in Go the cause of the dockerd error I am receiving?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I do understand your point but the question is one, how to set up a tls connection with a docker container in Go. This requires a correct TLS configuration, reachable containers from the host in order for the Go code to make sense for the reader. The prerequisites are ready I abstracted the details as much as possible but I just wanted to make sure I am not making any major error.

Comment: "*From what I understand the docker API is reachable from the container, am I correct about this assumption?*" - This is a separate question, and should be treated as such.

Comment: I reformulated the post so it only contains one question. I consider my assumptions correct until someone considers them as the cause of the dockerd error.

Comment: not sure about the solution but this looks wrong: `u.RawQuery = "stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&logs=1&stream=1&tty=1"`, because out, err, and in cannot all be on descriptor 1. Try 0 for stdin. also it looks like question 1 is answered becuase you would get a different error (not about handshake) if the "remote" api was unreachable.

Comment: I think it receives true/false values, I tried with true or false but no success. Also, I just realized that exec has no websocket support. Apparently the exec with ws proposal was declined https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9372 . So I am not sure if its possible to remotely connect to a container and start a bash session to it with websockets.